# Redirecting pages with the header thing

Tags: php, html, header

I know how to redirect a page using the header thing. The problem is that when I redirect using this header it scrolls the page to the top. Let me clear it now.

I have a form on a page which has an action to sample.php. The sample.php redirects to the same page where the form was. But it takes the page to the top. I mean it scrolls to the top. I need it to be in the same place where the scroll button was earlier before redirecting. Is it possible to do this thing. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to scroll to `<div id="here">` or `<form id="here">` on `sample.php` redirect to:

```
http://www.website.com/sample.php#here
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible, through use of JavaScript, but it would be easier to define an anchor and point the form there. For instance, `<form action="sample.php#scrollhere" method="post" id="scrollhere">`.